# Apache mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using the following URL:

```
http://hostname/Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod/product/?mid=1&pid=B004JPPO94&src=hmb_numark
```

(also, the 'Numark.. to ipod..' is the 'title')

I want to write a rule to redirect this URL to the following URL

```
http://hostname/product/?sid=1&pid=B004JPPO94&title=Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod&src=hmb_numark
```

note the first url contains mid and pid while the second contains pid and sid.

Can someone please help me out and direct me towards the rewrite rule that would work for this case?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Old URL:

```
http://hostname/Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod/product/?mid=1&pid=B004JPPO94&src=hmb_numark
```

New URL:

```
http://hostname/product/?sid=1&pid=B004JPPO94&title=Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod&src=hmb_numark
```

I have no idea if that's what you actually want as you haven't fully specified the question. This rule also expects that mid, pid and src are all present in the URL and in the given order.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mid=(.*)&pid=(.*)&src=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)/product/ product/?sid=%1&pid=%2&title=$1&src=%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but this is not working. I am getting 404 error

Comment: What's the exact URL you typed in your browser? It should not be possible for this to lead to a 404 error even if it's incorrect.

Comment: Also, what URL did the address bar show when on the 404 page?

Comment: ok, heres the thing...i might have tweaked the url's int he question cos i thought it would make answering it easier...the actual url formats are as follows....
http://hostname/Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod/product/?mid=1&pid=B004JPPO94&src=hmb_numark
which is to be redirected to the following: (also, the 'Numark.. to ipod..' is the 'title'
http://hostname/product/?sid=$2&pid=$3&title=$1&src=$4
.
note the first url contains mid and pid while the second contains pid and sid.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting this in a comment. It's near impossible to read here and makes the Q&A useless for anyone but yourself (helping you personally is only a side-benefit to experts building a repository of answers to recurring programming questions).

Comment: It's also now impossible to answer. You have different variables in the first URL and the second but haven't specified how they should be related. Where should `sid` come from? Why are you repeating `pid`, `title`, `src` twice in the query string?

Comment: sorry... pid remains pid...he mid is the same as sid...only the name has changed...the repeat of the title, pid and src has to be done...to explain the 'why' would take me half an hour

Comment: the new answer is almost correct.....see, the sid comes from the mid....the pid remains as the pid...and so do the title and src....
so, basically the resulting url that i want is::
http://hostname/product/?pid=B004JPPO94&sid=1&title=Numark-iDJ-Live-DJ-software-controller-for-iPad-iPhone-or-iPod&src=hmb_numark

Comment: Why did you just change your desired URL a 3rd time? Read your comment two up where you said the repeats are necessary, now you're saying you don't need them at all. I'm done with this. You know what to do at this point.

Comment: im so sorry...i misunderstood the word 'repeats'.....and now the current url's in the main question body and ACCURATE and are exactly what i want.....thanks and sorry